# multi-dimensional mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I need a single mysql table to contain both static and dynamic data
so the first data is standard inrormation like name email adress etc. and within that row I need a new dimension with dynamic data like last updated(date)
for example

```
Person 1| name| address| age|work record--->  within-> work record: experience|Qualifications
person 2| name| address| age|work record
person3 | name| address| age|work record
```

so person 1 may only have one column of experience and person 2 may have 5, so I need a new dimension to avoid creating a individual table for each person. Can this be done in mysql?

Comment: Sounds like an ordinary [one-to-many](http://sqlrelationship.com/one-to-many-relationship/) relationship...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is to have a second (and third) table for the experience and qualifications. (You may abstract these two into the same table if the data you want to store are similar)

You would then use a 1:n relation to your "person"-table, using the primary key of the person-table as foreign key in the experience and qualifications table.

The tables could look something like this:

```
PERSON table:
-------------
PersonID (Primary Key)
Name
Address
Age

QUALIFICATION table:
--------------------
QualificationID (Primary Key)
PersonID (Foreign key to Person table)
Qualification-field1
Qualification-field2
Qualification-fieldn

EXPERIENCE table:
-----------------
ExperienceID (Primary Key)
PersonID (Foreign key to Person table)
Experience-field1
Experience-field2
Experience-fieldn
```

Using constraints you would ensure that you can't have EXPERIENCE records that references non-existing PERSON records.

Comment: so if I wanted to insert valeus('x','y'z') INTO person 1, qualifications how would that go?

Comment: insert into qualifications VALUES (KEY, 1, 'x', 'y', 'z') - replacing "key" with some sequencenumber that is unique across all the entire qualifications-table.